# Prevent bloc from refreshing all items in the List

Tags: flutter, listview, bloc, state-management

I am trying to understand bloc, but it seems like I am doing something wrong.
Every time I trigger an event, all items get refreshed!

This is a list of expandable views. When you tap on an item it changes in size and expands.

Event Class:

```
class HelpEvents {}

class ExpandView extends HelpEvents {}

class CollapseView extends HelpEvents {}
```

State Class:

```
class HelpStates {}

class ToggleViewState extends HelpStates {}
```

Bloc Class:

```
class HelpScreenBloc extends Bloc<HelpEvents, HelpStates> {

  HelpScreenBloc() : super(HelpStates()){ //InitialState


    /// When user press Expand
    on<ExpandView>((event, emit) async {
      emit(ToggleViewState()); //first state
    });

    /// When user press Collapse
    on<CollapseView>((event, emit) {
      emit(ToggleViewState()); //collapsed state
    });
  }
}
```

---

List Item:

```
bool isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),

      child: Material(
          elevation: appElevation,

          child: BlocBuilder<HelpScreenBloc, HelpStates>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              print("This is supposed to run Once");


              return InkWell(

                onTap: () {

                  // <-- Trigger Event ---------------- here

                  if(!isExpanded) {
                    context.read<HelpScreenBloc>().add(ExpandView());

                  } else {
                    context.read<HelpScreenBloc>().add(CollapseView());
                  }

                  isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                },

                child: Expanded(
                  child: AnimatedContainer(
                      height: isExpanded ? 150 : 70,
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 180),

                      child: const Text("text"),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          )
      ),
    );
  }
```

I also noticed that using state variables changed every item in the list! This is why I was forced to use a global bool inside my widget (`isExpanded`),
but I guess this is not very clean? like it should be better if I manipulated variables inside of my state classes and referenced them using `state.variable`

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to add 2 states not only one and do the widget build based on your state not a global variable this why we use state management in order to get rid of global vars and refresh the UI based on states

use 2 states like Open & collapsed

Comment: When I tried that, all items in the list expanded! Which is the main problem I want to fix

Comment: You just need to "provide" a new bloc instance for each of your "items". Or have a single bloc, but with added logic to handle a "list of items"

Comment: but your code here represent only single container not a list of it

Comment: you need to check the current index if you are working on a list 
like : list[index].height = 150:70

Comment: So, I should put my bloc level code on the list itself not the item widget?

Comment: But then wouldn't that change height of every index on that list?